# Eclipse not detecting HTC desire as device

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, android

I've been developing an Android app on Ubuntu 10.10 with Eclipse (using HTC Desire) for the past few months without any major problems. Today however, I was testing some stuff and for some reason Logcat wasn't outputting certain messages (timing logs to measure performance). So I foolishly thought there might be something wrong with the adb connection. I went into the phone settings and unticked USB debugging and then re-ticked it. Now Eclipse will refuse to detect the device.

I have the proper udev rules set up, and I've tried restarting both the phone and computer to no avail. Changing USB ports doesn't help. Like I said, this was working fine for the last few months and now all of a sudden because I reapplied a setting, it went kaput.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it. Had to do a factory reset on the phone. No biggie but annoying nonetheless.